# In Daum PotPlayer how can I copy a timestamp to the clipboard?

Tags: audio, clipboard, transcription

I am listening to audio conversations and from that creating a summary of the interaction. It is not a verbatim transcription. I need to drop timestamp citations everywhere. How can I copy and paste a timestamp. Currently I am having to eyeball the timestamp and then type "[41:58]"

Comment: http://www.visualsubsync.org/ may be a solution but it appears as if one would have to put the bullet points chronologically. My conversations go all over the show so that in the summary, a point in the final minute maybe right next to a point discussed 15 minutes earlier.

Comment: Maybe I will try [Express Scribe](http://nch.invisionzone.com/index.php?/topic/13839-time-stampiing-using-express-scribe/)

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing the eyeball method as well and finally discovered the option is here

Misc-Other-Copy current playback elapsed time to clipboard